# What are properties in C++/CLI?

Tags: properties, c++-cli

I saw in the term `property` in C++ code. I think it's connected to C++/CLI.

What is it exactly?

Comment: where did you see it? Give full sentence please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was indeed connected to C++/CLI (unmanaged C++ doesn't really have a notion of properties).

> **Properties are entities that behave like fields but are internally handled by getter and setter accessor functions.** They can be scalar properties (where they behave like a field) or indexed properties (where they behave like an array). In the old syntax, we had to specify the getter and setter methods directly in our code to implement properties - wasn't all that well received as you might guess. In C++/CLI, the syntax is more C#-ish and is easier to write and understand.

Taken from this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/CppCliProperties.aspx

Also see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379617%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#vs05cplus_topic10) on properties in C++/CLI.

Sample code:

```
private:
   String^ lastname;

public:
   property String^ LastName
   {
      String^ get()
      {
         // return the value of the private field
         return lastname;
      }
      void set(String^ value)
      {
         // store the value in the private field
         lastname = value;
      }
   }
```

Comment: you wrote: "roperties are entities that behave like fields".  what are fields?

Comment: @lital: A field is just a variable that is declared directly in a `class` or `struct`. It can be any type (`String`, `bool`, `int`, etc.). You'll sometimes see fields referred to as "member variables" because they are variables that are a member of their containing type (the `class` or `struct`). The point of properties is to expose those private fields publicly to conform with bject-oriented design principles.

Comment: Fields are variables accessible from any method in the class. But before you ask what is class, I suggest you read a few articles about OOP in C++.

Comment: Yup, reading up on object-oriented programming would be a very good idea if you're trying to wrap your mind around all of this. Although, if you're learning C++/CLI, you might be better off reading a book about OOP in C#. There are *lots* of differences between unmanaged C++ and C++/CLI.

Comment: Well no, they (C++/CLI properties) don't behave like fields (or member variables, if you prefer).  That's sort of the point.  They are accessed with the same syntax (except taking the address is forbidden) but have different behavior.  Furthermore, it's perfectly possible to write properties in unmanaged C++, you just don't have the `property` keyword to help you.

Comment: @Ben: Perhaps "behave" is the wrong word. When I read the excerpt, I interpreted "behave" to mean that they are accessed using the same syntax and provide similar functionality. Not that every aspect of their behavior is identical. Either way, considering the original question, I didn't think a detailed discussion of the nuances was going to be particularly helpful. Feel free to add that as an answer for future visitors. Additionally, my point was not that you couldn't simulate properties with unmanaged C++, but that properties are not first class citizens of the language as with C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Yep indeed this is Microsoft's version of managed c++ code or C++/CLI.  Now not only do you still have to write Get & Set Methods but you also need to define it as a property.  *I will say as much as I hate the extra typing the 'Read Only' and 'Write Only' versions of the property is pretty neat.*

But unnecessary in un-managed c++!!!

For instance you could write in a class (will do exactly the same thing!):

```
std::string GetLastName() const { return lastname;}
void SetLastName(std::string lName) { lastname = lName;}
```

The 'const' made sure it 'GET' was read only, and the set was clear.  No need to define a property or add the confusion of String^ vs. std::string....